# How to change Xfce top menu bar (theming doesn't help)

Tags: linux, themes, xfce, color-theme

I have Debian Wheezy with XFCE 4.8 installed and I'm stuck with [file menu bar](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg94/scaled.php?server=94&filename=97703623.jpg&res=medium) (top menu bar present on almost all the windows).

[image: Arrows are pointing on the window area I'm talking about]

I've tried Appearance, Windows manager and Compiz config, but no matter what I change or tweak that file menu bar remains the same: gray backgroud + a cheezy italic font.

P.S. I've also tried to modify theme files (Menubar section), but I haven't figured out what to put instead of the default value.

Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem too in DreamLinux 5.
I edited menu.rc in /home/me/.themes/Go-Touch/gtk-2.0/Menu, where Go-Touch is theme I use. I found this code:
`font_name = "Bold Italic 9"`
then changed it to:
`font_name = "9"`
After reboot, the menu bar is neither bold or italic, just size 9.
Hopefully you'll solve it too.